# Using Palettes in Mathematica Online

Tags: palettes, mathematica-online

my student is using the online version of Mathematica for my class; it appears to not have a palette feature for typing formatted input?  This was kind of shocking to me; why wouldn't there be a palette?  Surely, I'm just missing something.

Is anyone familiar with Mathematica online, who knows how to use palettes there?  How is it accessed?

Comment: When you are editing a notebook, there is a menu item Insert / Special Characters... which opens a menu on the right.

Comment: I'm afraid Mathematica Online has a long way to go before it can be a true rival to Mathematica the computer application.

Answer (score 2):

At least as of 2017-07-14: 2d input in uploaded notebooks is blocked from editing, it doesn't have 2d input pallettes, and the keyboard shortcuts for 2d input are disabled.