# Mathematical Typesetting in Mathematica Online

Tags: formatting, text, mathematica-online

Is there any way to insert mathematical typesetting into text cells in Mathematica Online?

I'm a teacher and I want my students to be able to do their assignments using Mathematica Online and hand them in for me to look through. I would like them to include relevant formulas (e.g. the area of a triangle, or Pythagoras' theorem), when they describe their solutions. However, when I try to insert mathematical typesetting using the keyboard shortcuts suggested here (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html) - e.g. "shift"+"(" to start the typesetting og "shift"+"_" to write in subscript - nothing happens. As far as I can see, Mathematica Online doesn't have Palettes and therefore I cannot use e.g. the Basic Math Input pallette accessable in the desktop version.

Is it just not an option when using Mathematica Online?

Comment: A similar question is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121935/using-palettes-in-mathematica-online?rq=1